# What kind of Caiman is this and what is on it's nose?

Tags: species-identification, symbiosis, diptera

I was able to snap a good picture in the Manù Parque Nacional in Peru. When I reviewed the pictures in more details I noticed something on it's nose, that resemble insects. What are those? Is it a known symbiosis? What do they gain?
Also our guide called it a "white river caiman", is this accurate?
And lastly: It seems one teeth is sticking out on top of it's mouth. By looking at the shape of the jaw it looks pretty natural. Is this common for caimans?
Picture for reference:
[image: Caiman]
I took the picture around here:
[image: Map Manù]
Nose only:
[image: Caiman nose]
Photo taken around May 2018.